# Changing the player object into a Prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a Prop Hunt game involving transforming into an object that is encountered by the player. To do this, the player will be observing the object with a raycast from the camera, and changing is appearance to mimic the object. The two issues that I have are;

1. I am unsure how to create a reference to the prefab of the game object that is being targeted.
2. I am unsure how to alter the prefab of the player.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is not a good question for stack overflow, because it is mainly opinion based and has [little to do with programming](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. 
Also, you should probably go to [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) or a real discussion board for questions like this. 
You will not get the right answer for this question, just answers, and you won't be able to discuss the issue properly on a Q and A page like SO.

Comment: You can't reference the prefab at runtime--you will have what you need with the GameObject reference.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you wanna destroy gameObject and give its properties
to player

```
 void Update() {

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit))
        {
            GameObject obj = hit.collider.gameObject;

            if (obj.CompareTag("prop"))
            {
                // or check that obj has needed component

                Mesh mesh = obj.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
                GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
                //also you can copy position, rotation, bounds, hp etc
                Destroy(obj); //
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is a really basic and dirty code but it probably works